# Why can't add a row to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 370864*493 dataset, I want to add a new row at the tail of the data set. I have tried Dataframe.loc[370864]=.... and Dataframe.append(). Both methods didn't work as my expectation.But the same code can work on a smaller data set, just 20 thousand rows. I hope to know the reason. The size of dataset is 1.6G. I use pandas and My IDE is spyder. The image shows more detail. The data source is UCSC cancer browser, LUAD methylation data.[The tail of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1apUH.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

"""
get clinical information and count number of M0 and M1
"""
def get_Metastasis(sampleID_list,df_clinical):
    num_M0=0
    num_M1=0
    list_Metastasis=[]
    list_Metastasis.append('Metastasis')
    for ID in sampleID_list:
        row_number=df_clinical.loc[df_clinical.sampleID==ID].index[0]
        list_Metastasis.append(df_clinical.loc[row_number,'pathologic_M'])
    for i in range(1,len(list_Metastasis)):
        if list_Metastasis[i]!="M0" and isinstance(list_Metastasis[i],str):
            list_Metastasis[i]="M1"
            num_M1+=1
            list_Metastasis[i]=1
        elif list_Metastasis[i]=="M0":
            num_M0+=1
            list_Metastasis[i]=0
#        else:
#            list_Metastasis[i]=None

    return list_Metastasis, num_M1, num_M0




"""
read Data
"""
path_for_clinical_data="clinical_data"                            
path_for_genomicMatrix="genomicMatrix"
df_clinical = pd.read_table(path_for_clinical_data)
df_genomicMatrix = pd.read_table(path_for_genomicMatrix)
df_genomicMatrix=df_genomicMatrix.dropna(axis=0)      ##get rid of row include nan
"""
Add metastasis information
"""
sampleID_list=list(df_genomicMatrix.columns.values)
sampleID_list=sampleID_list[1:]
list_M=[]

list_M,num_M1,num_M0=get_Metastasis(sampleID_list,df_clinical)
df_genomicMatrix.loc[len(df_genomicMatrix)]=list_M             ## Here is the problem.
```

Here is the result:

```
        sample  TCGA-44-4112-01  TCGA-NJ-A4YP-01  TCGA-86-8278-01  \
485566  cg15678817          0.02110           0.0961          -0.1652   
485567  cg14483317         -0.41520          -0.4051          -0.4117   
485573  cg10230711         -0.42750          -0.3067          -0.4182   
485574  cg16651827          0.22345           0.2358           0.2007   
485576  cg07883722          0.36660           0.3932           0.4155
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What is your expected result and what  are the actual results?

Comment: The row is not added to the dataframe.

Comment: So, when you do `df_genomicMatrix.loc[370864]=list_M` there are no error messages? And the `DataFrame` isn't modified at all? You need to be more precise and ideally give us some code that reproduces the behavior you are seeing that you want to remedy.

Comment: no error message, the new image show the last five rows. The correct result is the last line should the combination of 1 , 0 and nan.

Comment: You really shouldn't be posting images, post the results in the question. Anyway, you realize that the tail of your DataFrame has a row index in the 485566 range, so clearly `df_genomicMatrix.loc[370864]` is NOT the right answer. You should try Jakub's suggestion of using the `len` of the DataFrame instead.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `df_genomicMatrix.loc[370864]`

Comment: yes, this index exists, just some biological data in that row.